# A profit max problem in a segmented market with a transfer fee

Tags: profit-maximization

This must be a standard profit maximization problem, but I'm not seeing an example in my textbook. We have a monopolized market in two segments, each with its own demand function.

$$ {Q}_{1} = 35 - {P}_{1} $$
$$ {Q}_{2} = 50 - 2{P}_{2} $$

There is a cost of $3 to demanders to transport goods between the market segments. It's ambiguous to me whether this is a fee collected by the supplier (an example might be a fund transfer fee between two services sold by the same bank) or is just a cost to demanders (for example a bridge toll) and also whether it means a cost per unit or something like a market entrance fee. If it's like a market fee collected by the supplier, then this is like a tariff to the transfer group and we could have a four part revenue function:

$$ 
R = {R}_{1} + {R}_{1t} + {R}_{2} + {R}_{2t}$$
where
$${R}_{1} = {P}_{1}*{Q}_{1} \\
{R}_{2} = {P}_{2}*{Q}_{2} \\
{R}_{1t} = 3+ {P}_{1}*{Q}_{1t} \\
{R}_{2t} = 3+ {P}_{2}*{Q}_{2t}
$$

And if the transport fee is per unit, something like
$$ 
{R}_{1} = {P}_{1}*{Q}_{1} + {P}_{1}*{Q}_{1t}\\
{R}_{2} = {P}_{2}*{Q}_{2} + {P}_{2}*{Q}_{2t} \\
{R}_{1t} = 3{Q}_{2t}+ {P}_{1}*{Q}_{1t} \\
 {R}_{2t} = 3{Q}_{1t}+ {P}_{2}*{Q}_{2t}$$

And if the cost is not a fee collected by the supplier but just a cost to demanders, the effect on demand depends on individual budgets and utility functions because the aggregate demand function is per unit and not per instance of market engagement (or per consumer). Is this correct? If so, then how do we set up the profit maximization?  Could we use Lagrange with total market quantity constraints (e.g., ${Q}_{1} = {Q}_{1l}+{Q}_{1t}$)? Any other suggestions are appreciated.